# How to portforward a site

Tags: port-forwarding, synology

We have a website, and my superiors asked me to install the mail server that is packaged with Synology. As I mess around with port forwarding I was able to set the mail server and the NAS to connect in the internet (meaning I can now access the NAS through internet).

The problem is the website is gone.

How should I fix it? I am using a ZyXEL router and because of my idiocy I cannot remember the default settings in the port forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites typically run on port 80 and should be the default port. I would suspect you've changed all the ports to forward to your NAS. You need to convert it back to port 80.

This will then remove your mail server, but you can specificy the port after the domain name, eg, www.mysite.com:1234  (using port 1234).

You may be able to control this using different domain names, but it does depend on your set up...

Comment: Thanks sir! I have a follow up if you don't mind. What Server IP should I use? Because if I portforward the public ip and I type the url of our site, it shows the welcome page our router.

Comment: Well, this is a different question (And this sites rules are not to ask extra questions here, but instead, do feel free to post a new question (but research first). I know about the web side, not totally sure about the NAS section of your question so you'll probably get answers from more knowledgeable people than I if you post a new question! :)

Comment: you need to port forward port 80 to the serverhosting the website